# Как исправить сетку bootstrap columns при размере окна браузера ≥1200px

Tags: bootstrap

Есть такая структура html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="width: 15rem;">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="width: 15rem;">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="width: 15rem;">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="width: 15rem;">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="width: 15rem;">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="width: 15rem;">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Получается, как на картинке с желтым фоном. А необходимо чтобы было как на картинке с зеленым фоном.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем вы юзайете процентную сетку и при этом задаете width для элементов?

Comment: width задает фиксированную ширину для элемента, а сетка позволяет разместить неограниченное количество элементов по 6 в ряд. Или это можно сделать более элегантно?

Comment: сетка задает правила для width, которые вы перекрываете инлайн стилями. чтобы разместить по 6 в ряд, надо использвать `col-2` а не `col`

Comment: Благодарю! Все сделал. Работает как о планировал!

Comment: а чтобы было по 6 в ряд для больших экранов, используйте `col-xl-2`